# Did Microsoft hide the 'Power buttons and lid' category by default in advanced power settings starting from version 2004?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management, power-options

I recently just upgraded to Windows 10 version 2004. Before that, I created a power plan in addition to the default one, which is used to keep the computer awake seeding torrents, and doing [BOINC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing) tasks.

Thus in that power plan, I set the "Lid close action" to "Do nothing" in advanced power settings. When I upgraded to version 2004, the category "Power buttons and lid" [is not visible anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTmOW.png). [This is what it would appear before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA9Gy.png), I know how to use [commands to unhide it again](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/add-or-remove-lid-close-action-from-power-options-in-windows.16498/), but it looks like the update has hidden all of the subcategory options (Lid close action, Power buttons action, Lid open action). When I execute the command, only the subcategory 'Lid close action' and the category containing it showed up, and not all of them.

I have no idea if it was Microsoft that hide them or am I just mistaking that with some software failures?

Comment: I always access them using Control Panel (icon view)>Power options

Comment: It varies with the manufacturer, the date of manufacture (how new), and how the manufacturer adapted Windows 10 to their computer.  Sometimes power settings are in Control Panel; sometimes in Settings, System, Power.

Comment: Also, Group Policies in the registry can hide those settings, so MS may have applied changes there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this everything you want:
[image]

After my own ordeal with displaying "System Unattended Sleep Timeout", which can prematurely darken the screen bfore the designatged time, and helping another user with a differnt settng, I wrote a script to query all available Power options, display them in a grid control with their current visibility state, and allow the user to select options and toggle their visivbility.

When you run the code below, you will be presented with a GridView control listing the option's:

- Attributes(visibility) `1` = Disabled   `2` = Enabled
- GUID
- Name

[image]

Although you can just scroll through the options, the GridView control allows you to filter using the **`Add Criteria`** button in the upper left:
[image]

Select the rows with the opitons whose Attributes you wish to toggle. Use + to multi-select rows. Then click "**`OK`**"

### Restart for changes to take effect

---

Copy & Paste the following code into an ***Administrator*** **PowerShell** window. Press  to execute.

```
Function Toggle-PowerSettingsVisibility {
    $Title         = 'Select option(s) to toggle visibility'
    $PowerSettings = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings'
    @( [PSCustomObject]@{
            Attributes  = 0
            PSChildName = '{ -- No Changes -- }'
            Name        = ' "Safety" row to clear selection'
    } ) +
    @( Get-ChildItem $PowerSettings -Recurse | ? Property -contains 'Attributes' | Get-ItemProperty |
        Select Attributes, PSCHildName,
               @{ N = 'Name' ; E = { $_.FriendlyName.Split(',')[-1] }} ) | Sort PSChildName |
    Out-GridView -Passthru -Title $Title | ForEach {
        $Splat = @{
            Path  = Resolve-Path "$PowerSettings\*\$($_.PSChildName)"
            Name  = 'Attributes'
            Value = $_.Attributes -bXor 0x0000003 
        }
        Set-ItemProperty @Splat
    }
}
Toggle-PowerSettingsVisibility
```